# Minimum edge in a set of edges which connects a graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree

The following is an example from my graph theory and algorithm course:

Let `A` be a minimal subset of edges of a weighted undirected graph `G` (distinct weight), such that if we remove `A` from `G` then `G` becomes disconnected.  The lightest edge in `A` must be in any MST.

**Why this is a correct fact?** I couldn't understand it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @MarcelSonderegger thank so much, really this is example in my book.

Answer (score 5):

According to the definition of minimal edge cut:

> A minimal edge cut is an edge cut such that if any edge is put back in the graph, the graph will be reconnected.

In the following figure:

[image]

The set, A = {a, b, c, d} is a minimal edge cut.

If A is removed from G, the graph becomes disconnected.

Now, the property: **"lightest edge in A must be in any MST"** can be explained by the **Cut Property**:

[image]

Therefore the statement is **true**, because,

The **lightest edge of the set A**  = **e** = min(a, min(b, min(c,d))) will be the part of MST.

Comment: you means by these minimal edge cut we connect two set of vertexes (cross a cut) so lightest edge that cross a cut among all other edges in A, is select to be on MST. am I right completely?

Comment: Yes. You got it right. It will be part of MST

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I think of it.  It's given that *A* is a set of edges that when removed disconnects *G*.  We could say that *A* connects (at least) two subsets of nodes in *G*, *G1* and *G2*.  There can be no edges linking *G1* and *G2* that don't go through *A*, because otherwise the connection of *G1* and *G2* would not depend on *A*.  Also denote *m* as the minimum edge within *A* (not *necessarily* the minimum of *G*, although it could be!).

So the question is, can you make the minimum path from *G1* to *G2* through *A* without taking its minimum edge *m*?  Well think of another subgraph which is all of the nodes which contain an edge within *A*.  So at least one node from *G1* and one node from *G2* (such that they are connected through *A*).  The MST of this subgraph must include *m*, because a [MST must include the smallest edge weight](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681816/must-a-minimum-weight-spanning-tree-for-a-graph-contain-the-least-weight-edge-of).  And the MST of *G* must include the MST of *A*, else we would be getting from *G1* to *G2* in a suboptimal way.

Comment: what do you mean by "(not necessarily the minimum of the entire graph)."

Comment: and the last part I couldn't understand is:  another subgraph which is made up of A as well as the nodes in G1 and G2 directly connected to A...

Comment: @LeimMani, by the "entire graph", I meant *G* - *m* is the minimum of *A* edges, but doesn't necessarily have to be the minimum edge for *G*.  This was vague, so I have corrected.  And for the subgraph, I just mean that *A* is a set of edges so is not a graph and cannot have an MST itself.  So I suggested taking the nodes in *G1* and *G2* which touch an edge in *A*.  But a clearer way to say this would be any nodes that have an edge in *A*.  This subgraph MST must contain *m*.